# What is Android's SharedPreferences equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, persistence

I'm trying to port an Android application to a Java desktop application. The android application is using a `SharedPreferences` object to store some data. Is there an equivalent in Java of this class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [the Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/) out. It has the same idea and use cases as the `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` is something specific to Android.

Making it a desktop aplication you will have to implement your own storage system to store your preferencies in an implementation dependent backing store.

You can achieve this using the [Core Java™ Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

You have to manage reading and writing the file, but it might be good enough!

Comment: I know about Properties class, but was asking if there is an equivalent, so it reduces the amount of work.

Comment: No, there is no direct equivalent. SharedPreferences is part of Android's API, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to store data in Java application. Depends on the scope of data you store, is it on session scope, application scope or anything else.

If you are looking something like SharedPrefereces, maybe you can read/write the data to System/User Environment. I don't know if it will match you need.

```
public class Env {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String env: args) {
            String value = System.getenv(env);
            if (value != null) {
                System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                                  env, value);
            } else {
                System.out.format("%s is"
                    + " not assigned.%n", env);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html).

It allows to manage properties as simple Java POJOs and store it to a XML file (Just what SharedPreferences are, an XML file) for persistence and retrieval.

Plain simple.